# How to get aws service with aws-sfk-php-zf2 v 2.0.*?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zend-framework2

I was using aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2 1.2.* and had to upgrade to 2.0.* and the AWS SDK is v3 now.

Before I called it using the code:

```
$this->s3 = $serviceLocator->get('aws')->get('s3');
```

But now its returning this error:

> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for aws

Couldn't find the difference in the migration documentation.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an way that worked for me.

It's like that now:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$this->s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
               'key' => $this->config['aws']['key'],
               'secret' => $this->config['aws']['secret'],
            ),
            'region' => $this->config['aws']['region'],
            'version' => '2006-03-01'
        ));
```

Comment: If you use this method you're neglecting the module, so you can aswell go ahead and discard/remove the module from your project. Just add `aws/aws-sdk-php` directly to your composer requirements. Unless you actually do use the viewhelpers/plugins that come along with the module.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fetching the service by the key: `Aws` you should now use the FQCN of the SDK class.

```
use Aws\Sdk as Aws;

$aws = $serviceLocator->get(Aws::class);
```

See the [module.config.php](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2/blob/2.0.1/config/module.config.php#L17) of the `aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2` module.

Comment: As you've upgraded to a newer version of the module it also uses a newer version of the SDK. So you should read the documentation of the SDK in how to get the S3 service. Take a look at [createS3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/3.44.0/src/Sdk.php#L213)